# Is there anyway to view metrics for each specific endpoint in an API hosted in lambda functions on AWS through cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I need the metrics (latency, availability) from cloudwatch because I need to measure right at the API gateway. Is there a way to filter for each endpoint?